# Grease pencil curve editing doesn't work

Tags: bezier-curves, grease-pencil

In Blender 2.93.5 grease pencil 2D animation edit mode curve editing doesn't work. The Bezier points, lines, and handles show up but can't be moved. Am I missing something? Full disclosure: I'm a total blender newb.

Steps to recreate:

1. Create new 2d animation, add a simple curve in draw mode
2. Switch to edit mode
3. Select "Select Mode: Select only points" and "Curve Editing"
4. Select a point on the curve
5. Bezier line and handles appear but can't be moved with mouse or pen

Same result on:

- Macbook Pro 2019 Intel macOS 11.6
- Macbook Pro 2021 M1 Max macOS 12.0.1

Comment: For me in 2.93.5, I can't select-drag a control point or handle, unless I have selected the move tool in the tool panel (The one with the four arrowheads. But using the tool it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply the way Blender Grease Pencil works: in edit mode left click (or pen click) is simply selecting. To move and edit curves enable Proportional editing (shortcut O), press G (or select Move tool)scroll mouse wheel, move and confirm with left click.

Try also sculpt mode, which has tools to move, smooth, emboss, empower strenght ..., and it's well designed for pen tablets.

[image],

Comment: beat me by 50 seconds ;)

Comment: Funny when it happens .... :)

Answer (score 2):

In 2.93.5, it appears that left mouse drag doesn't work unless you've selected the move tool:

[image: Showing the move tool]

Once I've done that, instead of the default, which is the box select tool (arrow in dotted box at the top of the tools)  everything works as expected.

With the box select tool, the default, selected, you can select the handle or control point, but you have to type <kbd>G</kbd> to start the move.

To switch between tools, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>Space Bar</kbd>.  It will popup a selection menu:

[image: Tool select menu]

You don't have to navigate in that menu to a tool name and click it, by the way. Each tool has a shortcut letter on the right of its menu entry.  Typing that letter is the same as clicking the menu entry.